# raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")

Tags: opencv

So i was doing feature extraction in opencv using python. I got the above mentioned error. The Image data cannot be converted to float. I dont understand the error. The code i used is:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('template.jpg',0)
img2 =cv2.imread('match.jpeg',0)

orb= cv2.ORB_create()
k1,d1=orb.detectAndCompute(img,None)
k2,d2=orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf=cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches =bf.match(d1,d2) 
matches=sorted(matches,key=lambda x:x.distance)

img3=cv2.drawMatches(img,k1,img2,k2,matches[:10],None,flags=2)
plt.imshow(img3)
plt.show()
```

Help me out solving the error. I even referred to similar questions asked here. I didnot understand any. I'm jus a beginner..so try explaining a bit easily.

Thank you..

Comment: Generally such errors come with other useful information, such as the stack trace, which tells you where in your code the error occurred. Don't disregard this information, it's there to help you. (That means you should also include it in your question)

Answer (score 2):

This error usually means that you aren't reading in the image properly. I would add some code like this to make sure you are actually getting the images:

```
path1="template.jpg"
if os.path.isfile(path1):
    img1 = cv2.imread(path1, 0)
else:
    print ("The file " + path1 + " does not exist.")
```